# jQuery Ajax form validation isn't working, not sure why

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so I have some jQuery code, HTML, and PHP I will post to give you guys a picture of what I am working with.  As far as I can see, everything looks right but it isn't working.  Even my .preventDefault() isn't preventing the form from submitting.  I think it has to do with the fact that I am using a bootstrap model to hold he form, but idk why it would cause the issue.  I don't have much experience with working with bootstrap though. --Edit I have the form prevented from submitting, and only need help with the ajax part.  This is the first using ajax, from everything I have been researching I have it right, but i'm always getting error messages back from ajax.  The error: function() is fired everytime, and I don't know how to find out why.  There has to be some syntax wrong somewhere I have looked in the console and the username and password variables are assigned right at run-time.

jQuery:

```
  $("#loginForm").submit(function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (($('#username2').val() != '') && ($('#password2').val() != ''))
    {
        var username = $('#username2').val();
        var password = $('#password2').val();
        //var dataString = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
        $('#errorMessage').fadeIn(400).html('<img src="http://192.168.1.78/mystery-machine/includes/images/icons/loading.gif"/>');
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://192.168.1.78/mystery-machine/includes/verfiyLogin.php",
                dataType: "text/html",
                data: {username: username, password: password},
                error: function(){
                    $('#errorMessage').html('<p>There was an error!</p>');
                },
                success:(function(data){
                    if (data == 'correct')
                    {

                        window.location.replace('http://192.168.1.78/mystery-machine');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#errorMessage').html(data);
                    }
                })
        });

    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
```

include 'functions.php';

```
$all_info = array();
$all_info[0] = $_POST['username'];
$all_info[1] = $_POST['password'];
$new_user = new gsn_login_object();
$new_user->login_start_up();
$new_user->set_user_data($all_info);
$id = session_id();
$uID = @$_SESSION[$id];

if($new_user->login_user() == true)
{
  echo 'correct';
}
else
{ 
  echo "The username and/or password you entered was incorrect!"; 
}
```

?>

Comment: If .preventDefault() don't work, have some javascript error, you see your console browser to check this?

Comment: I have gotten .prevent Default() to work now and yes you can get my console, will add it to post.

Comment: so your code works now?

Comment: No, I have gotten all the script to work but the ajax part, from what I understand, what you echo in the php file should be returned to the success function as text, so I either have a correct login or the div #errorMessage should display the error message that is echoed in the PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you open up your console I am sure it has a big error message in red that points to the line

```
$("#loginForm".submit(function(event)
             ^^^
```

You missed the closing `)`

I will point out the missing `)` after the selector.

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(event)
             ^^^
```

Comment: I thought the ) and ; come after the closing bracket when using a anonymous function like that

Comment: I pointed it out exactly now...

Comment: I'm sorry, I see what you are saying I was looking at my code and not the code I posted.  That was my fault, it was in correct syntax in my .js file.  My apologizes